# load template url by ajax call in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I want to send an ajax request to get jsp/html page for templateurl of modal.
 I have written by code like this.

```
 var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                    templateUrl: 'pages/recordingDetailPopup .jsp',
                    controller: 'FileDetailCtrl',
                    size: 'lg',
                    resolve: {
                        activeRecords: function () {
                            return inbnoxList;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

But I want to do something like thing like this

```
 var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                templateUrl: function(){
                $http.get('fileDetailJsp');
                },
                controller: 'FileDetailCtrl',
                size: 'lg',
                resolve: {
                    activeRecords: function () {
                        return inbnoxList;
                    }
                }
            });
```

How can I implement this functionality.Please suggest.

Comment: What would `$http.get('fileDetailJsp')` return? I guess it's not the template itself. Does the template URL change dynamically? Is this an indirection to return the name of the template to be used...? If so, you'd need something like `$http.get('fileDetailJsp').then(function(response) { $uibModal.open(...use something from response...); });`

Comment: $http.get('fileDetailJsp') will return path of the template file that will be used in template url

Answer (score 1):

`templateUrl` in your second snippet will return a promise and not the response of the `jsp` file.

In above scenario, you will need to first get the response from `jsp` and then invoke `.open` method on modal like below -

```
$http.get('fileDetailJsp').then(function(url){
      var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
            templateUrl: url,
            controller: 'FileDetailCtrl',
            size: 'lg',
            resolve: {
                activeRecords: function () {
                    return inbnoxList;
                }
            }
        });
}, function(){
  // error here
 });
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: hi it works but how to do this ion app.js where I have done  state routing.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `$http.get('fileDetailJsp');}`, it returns a [Promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). The moment that you call the `$uibModal.open`, the Promise is not prepared yet. That's why you get nothing. As @pdenes mentions that, you need something like :

```
$http.get('fileDetailJsp').then(function(response) {
   $uibModal.open(...use something from response...); 
});
```

Comment: how to get template url in app.js file where i have done state routing??

Comment: @Keshav `$http.get()` is to get the data from the server side, in which I thought your url stocks. But you mean the url is in the app.js? So why would you change your codes?

Comment: I have to get templateurl from server by sending $http request.How will i do this??

Comment: @Keshav you don't have to get the url from server, your first scenario works fine. so why would you change your scenario?

Comment: Its my requirement that get templateurl from $http request.It is mention in angular doc that i can call a function on angular templateurl but i could not understand how?? Wiil you see this link and suggest me   https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: @Keshav So its your requirement, you should know where the url stocks, and just get the url with $http.get().